# Solving recurrence relation with a sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve this recurrence relation, I have researched on how to solve it by trying to get rid of the sum however I wasn't able to do so.
$$S(a,b)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^b{\binom{b}{n}S(a,n)}}{2^a},a\in N, b\in N_0$$
$$S(a,0)=1$$

Comment: Surely, you are missing some initial conditions... otherwise $S(a,b)=0$ for all $a,b$ satisfies your recurrence as well.

Comment: $a$ seems to be non important. Notice that this is a Cauchy product of $1$ and $S,$ so the generating function is a multiplication. That will give you a functional equation.

Comment: Should the right-hand side of the uppermost equation really contain $S(a,b)$ if $n=b$?

Comment: Yeah it should @IV_ you could get rid of it by chaining the limit of the sum to b-1 instead of b and on the lower part $2^a-1$ instead of $2^a$

Comment: Multiplying both sides with $x^b/b!$ and summing you get  an exponential generating function of $S(a,b)$.

Comment: @JohannCigler I don't understand how multiplying both sides by that helps could you please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}S(a,j)=2^a S(a,n)$ for $n>0$ and $F(x)=\sum_j S(a,j)\frac{x^j}{j!}.$

Then we have  $e^x F(x)=\sum_n{\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}S(a,j)\frac{x^n}{n!}}=1+2^a(F(x)-1)=1-2^a+2^a F(x)$ and therefore $F(x)=\frac{2^a-1}{2^a-e^x}.$

**Edit**

Let $A(n,k)$ denote the Eulerian numbers and $a_n(t)=\sum_{j=0}^n A(n,j)t^j$ the Eulerian polynomials.
Then
$$\frac{t-1}{t-e^{z(t-1)}}= \sum_j a_n(t)\frac{z^n}{n!}.$$
Therefore $$S(a,n)=\frac{a_n(2^a)}{(2^a-1)^n}.$$

Comment: How does finding F(x) help with solving S(a,n) for any given n?

Comment: How could i apply this to different initial values?